# Caracteres especiales Codeigniter PHPExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Tengo una funcion que me extrae datos de una DB y los exporta a un archivo excel, el problema es que no muestra tildes ni caracteres especiales (N°)

Este es mi codigo:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I16', 'N° Serie');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

Lo que me imprime:

```
NÂ° Serie
```

utf8_encode() no me funciono, alguna ayuda... gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar utilizando **utf8_decode()**, hice un ejemplo sencillo para que te puedas guiar [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnheader('Content-type:%20application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=iso-8859-15');%5Cnheader('Content-Disposition:%20attachment;%20filename=nombre_archivo.xls');%5Cn%5Cn$contenido%20=%20'%3Ctable%20border=%221%22%20cellpadding=%222%22%20cellspacing=%220%22%20width=%22100%25%22%3E%5Cn%20%3Ccaption%3ETabla%20de%20pruebas%3C/caption%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3ECanci%C3%B3n%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3E%C3%91o%C3%B1o%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3E%C3%81rbol%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3ET%C3%A9rmino%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3EN%C2%BA%20Serie%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%3EN%C2%BA%20Serie%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%20%3C/table%3E';%5Cn%5Cnecho%20utf8_decode($contenido);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn), y con tu código quedarñias así:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I16', utf8_decode('N° Serie'));
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

todo dependiendo de como venga de la BD. Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias! ahora si me funciona! no se porque usaba encode en ves de decode...